# Initializing JSON object in TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm stuck at working with JSON. I need to create a simple JSON object and I keep on failing doing so. Here are my first attempts:

```
output: JSON; //declaration
this.output = {
"col1":{"Attribute1": "value1", "Attribute2": "value2", "Attribute3": "value3"},
"col2":{"Attribute1": "value4", "Attribute2": "value5", "Attribute3": "value6"}, 
"col3":{"Attribute1": "value7", "Attribute2": "value8", "Attribute3": "value9"} 
}
```

This doesn't work. I guess I should work with JSON.stringify function. Here's my attempt:

```
obj: any; //new object declaration
this.obj = {
"col1":{"Attribute1": "value1", "Attribute2": "value2", "Attribute3": "value3"},
"col2":{"Attribute1": "value4", "Attribute2": "value5", "Attribute3": "value6"}, 
"col3":{"Attribute1": "value7", "Attribute2": "value8", "Attribute3": "value9"} 
}
this.output.stringify(this.obj);
```

But this still invokes TypeError. So to summarize my question: how to properly create and initialize JSON object in TypeScript?

Comment: Your example doesn't make much sense to me. Firstly you can't declare output on the this scope like that, secondly it would be handy if you could provide the exact error you are getting

Comment: I posted solutions I made for my problem but they don't work fine. All I need to do is to correctly create a JSON object and initialize it in my TypeScript method. Code I posted is compileable - it doesn't show any errors but in console I can see TypeError "this.output is not defined"

Comment: Well, the correct solution would be to declare output on the scope of `this`

Answer (score 23):

I've eventually figured it out. All I had to do was to create data to "any" variable like this:

```
output: JSON;
obj: any = 
{
"col1":{"Attribute1": "value1", "Attribute2": "value2", "Attribute3": "value3"},
"col2":{"Attribute1": "value4", "Attribute2": "value5", "Attribute3": "value6"}, 
"col3":{"Attribute1": "value7", "Attribute2": "value8", "Attribute3": "value9"} 
};
```

and then cast it to JSON object:

```
this.output = <JSON>this.obj;
```

Comment: `JSON` is not the type of a JSON object, it's the type of the `JSON` parsing object *itself*.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh  This is such a valuable insight, hidden away in a comment! I was going to ask you the logical follow-up question, which is: What is the _correct_ type for JSON data but after simply checking the return type of `JSON.parse()`, the answer seems to be `any` 

Answer (score 14):

You can also do the following

```
const rememberUser:JSON = <JSON><unknown>{
        "username": this.credentialsForm.value.username,
        "password": this.credentialsForm.value.password
      }
```

Answer (score 10):

It worked for me in Angular 2.4.0 Stable by doing this:

```
var request: any = {};
request.allocation = allocationFigure;
```